# Expected response to be successful, got 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm using heroku with ruby on rails for a project, and when I try to run:

`heroku logs -t`

And I get this error:

`Expected response to be successful, got 500`

I cannot run `heroku run bash` too

Yesterday it was working fine. Somebody know what's wrong?

Thank you for the help,

**UPDATE**

I get this error now:

`ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443`

As said Dimitry_N the problem come from heroku. Here the status [heroku status](https://status.heroku.com)

Comment: I have the same problem right now.

Comment: i'm actually getting the same error when i run `heroku apps` and also i cannot push anything to heroku. it constantly returns `everything is up to date` when it isn't yet. seeing this makes me suspect something might be up with the heroku server?

Comment: Heroku had an API outtage and issues with backups and restores. Here is their Status app:  https://status.heroku.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dyn DNS is currently undergoing a serious DDoS attack and this affecting a huge number of popular sites.

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12759520